# Custom Domain as a unsigned type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm curious if it's possible to alter values converted to a domain's type. An example would be an unsigned integer domain type where the domain maps the integer literals 0 - 65535 to all valid values for a `SMALLINT`, -32768 - 32767. Example pseudo-code below.

```
CREATE DOMAIN USMALLINT AS SMALLINT
    CONSTRAINT CHECK (SET VALUE = VALUE - 32768 RETURNING TRUE);
```

But of course that is not valid syntax, specifically calling `SET` that way. Is something akin to this possible with rules and/or events, though?

I'm assuming that literals are just given the smallest enclosing SQL type, and that the literal is then converted to the domain type which triggers the constraints to be checked (as mentioned in the [CREATE DOMAIN documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html)).

Comment: The only way I can think of, is to use a domain with an `integer` and a check constraint to limit the values.

Comment: Why the custom domain and not a new data type? Then you can define the bespoke cast logic.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 can you give an example? I'm not sure how I'd implement that logic with a custom type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I assumed T-SQL had domains because they're a part of the SQL standard. I removed the tag.